# Find div aria label starting with certain text and then extract

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to locate the button element "Follow" because it contains the text of the user that you're going to follow.

Element:

```
<div aria-label="Follow @Visiongeo" role="button" tabindex="0" class="css-18t94o4 css-1dbjc4n r-42olwf r-sdzlij r-1phboty r-rs99b7 r-15ysp7h r-4wgw6l r-1ny4l3l r-ymttw5 r-o7ynqc r-6416eg r-lrvibr" data-testid="1676648952-follow" style="background-color: rgb(239, 243, 244);"><div dir="auto" class="css-901oao r-1awozwy r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-b88u0q r-1777fci r-rjixqe r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0" style="color: rgb(15, 20, 25);"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 css-bfa6kz r-poiln3 r-1b43r93 r-1cwl3u0 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0">Follow</span></span></div></div>
```

But the thing is, the text after **Follow**, which is @Visiongeo changes, so I don't want to particularly locate the element with specific text.

Instead, I want to locate this element, and then get the text that starts with "**@**" and write it to a text file.

My code:

```
for followers in wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow')]"))):
    file = open("testfile.txt", "a")
    file.write(followers)
    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

I get TimeoutException message when I use the above code. I think I'm way off from what I intend to do.

Comment: Can you share a link to the web page?

Comment: @Prophet It's a Facebook post I suppose ;)

Comment: @DebanjanB why not Twitter or Instagram or whatever else?

Comment: @Prophet https://twitter.com/Visiongeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element with *`aria-label`* as ***Follow @Visiongeo*** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *xpath* 1:

  ```
  //div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow') and contains(@data-testid, 'follow')]
  ```
- *xpath* 2:

  ```
  //div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow') and contains(@data-testid, 'follow')][//span[text()='Follow']]
  ```
- *xpath* 3:

  ```
  //div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow') and contains(@data-testid, 'follow')]//span[text()='Follow']//ancestor::div[1]//ancestor::div[1]
  ```

---

Inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631116/python-selenium-wait-for-several-elements-to-load/64770041#64770041) you can use:

```
for followers in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow') and contains(@data-testid, 'follow')]"))):
```

---

To parse the names of the followers you can use:

```
for followers in [my_elem.get_attribute("aria-label").split("@")[1] for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow') and contains(@data-testid, 'follow')]")))]:
```

Comment: I get error:

 for followers in wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@aria-label, 'Follow') and contains(@data-testid, 'follow')][//span[text()='Follow']]"))):
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable

Comment: @Cassano Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: I have a for loop, and I'm trying to get the text after Follow that contains username with @. And then write that to a textfile... I hope you got me right.

Comment: @Cassano Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: @Cassano Any feedback?