# Extract partial text from element link with python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In the below HTML, my goal is to return **zzde7e35d-8d9d-4763-95d2-9198684abb12**

```
<div class = container>    
    <a class="Blue-Button" data-type="patch" data-disable-with="Waiting" href="/market/opening/zzde7e35d-8d9d-4763-95d2-9198684abb12">Yes</a>
</div>
```

The problem is, I can't even seem to locate the URL within the div

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

link = example.url
driver.get(link)
URL = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"market")]')
print(URL)
```

Printing the above, I seem to get a bunch of random characters unrelated to the HTML at all, let alone the URL in question.

If it simplifies the issue, the number of characters that are returned will always be the same length, is indexing an easy work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the `href` you need to use `get_attribute('href')`
this will give you `/market/opening/zzde7e35d-8d9d-4763-95d2-9198684abb12` and then split() this and you will get the last element.

```
link = example.url
driver.get(link)
URL = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"market")]')
print(URL.get_attribute('href').split("/")[-1])
```

Output:

```
zzde7e35d-8d9d-4763-95d2-9198684abb12
```

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly missing a delay.
Instead of

```py
URL = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"market")]')
```

Try using

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

URL = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@href,"market")]'))).get_attribute("href")
print(URL)
```

Also you will have to extract the `href` attribute value from the returned web element object as shown in the code.
In case this still not worked check if the element you are trying to access inside iframe etc. Or maybe the locator is not unique etc.

Answer (score 0):

To print the partial value of the *href* attribute i.e. *`zzde7e35d-8d9d-4763-95d2-9198684abb12`* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Yes"))).get_attribute("href").split("/")[3])
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.Blue-Button[data-type='patch'][data-disable-with='Waiting'][href*='market']"))).get_attribute("href").split("/")[3])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='Blue-Button' and @data-type='patch'][@data-disable-with='Waiting' and contains(@href, 'market')]"))).get_attribute("href").split("/")[-1])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Find div aria label starting with certain text and then extract](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70524752/7429447)